# Where are the Vyuha lokas located?

Tags: vishnu, lokas, pancharatra

Vyuha refers to emanations of Lord Vishnu. There are 4 vyuha forms of Lord Vishnu:

1. Vasudeva
2. Sankarshana
3. Aniruddha
4. Pradyumna

Now, I have heard that each of these Vyuha forms of Lord Vishnu have their own lokas. My question: Where are these lokas located? Are the 4 Vyuha lokas a part of Vaikuntha itself or they have a separate location? Do the  Pāñcarātra Āgamas say anything about these lokas?

Comment: Vyuha Vasudeva lives in Shwetadvipa which is part of Bhuloka.  (As opposed to Para Vasudeva who lives in Paramapadam which is above all the 14 material Lokas.)  Sankarshana, Pradyumna, and Aniruddha live in Amoda, Pramoda, and Sammoda respectively.  And yes, all these places are described in the Pancharatra Agamas.

Comment: @Keshav Where are Amoda Pramoda and Sammoda located? It's interesting that the abode is named like a person, or does it imply 'Full Bliss', 'Divine Bliss' and 'Everlasting Bliss'? And how is it Shvetadvipa isn't one of the Modas?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan In which loka do humans live in?